# C# : get bool and string return

Tags: c#, oop

I am new to OOP and C# and I am hoping I am missing something basic here..I probably can use Tuples syntax here but I am trying to get this to work with basic OOP concepts.. I have a Validator class and if the inputs are not correct, I want to know why it failed. Here is my attempt..how to get 'Msg' string value from Main() ?  Warning ...bad code ahead...

```
class Validator
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }

        public string Msg { get; set; }


        public bool IsAgeValid()
        {
            if (Age < 18)
            {
                Msg = "Not old enough";
                return false;
            }
            else if (Age > 25)
            {
                Msg = "you are very old";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public bool IsLocationValid()
        {
            if (Location == "EARTH")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Msg = "sorry..only for humans";
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool IsValid()
        {
            if (IsAgeValid() && IsLocationValid())
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public string getErrorMessage()
        {

            return Msg;
        }

    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Validator myValidator = new Validator();
        myValidator.Age = 34;
        myValidator.Location = "EARTH";

        if(myValidator.IsValid())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("good");
        }
        else
        {
        // Not working- myValidator.getErrorMessage()
            Console.WriteLine("bad because " + myValidator.getErrorMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Question, do you want to know only one validation at once or all the validations that don't pass an object you're validating? It depend at your answer, how to design your validation mechanism

Comment: Very unclear what you have problem with. Is your question "what is syntax to get property value in C#"?Also make sure to review [MCVE] guide on posting code - if code does not compile (like one shown) but you have problem with something else it is very hard to know what kind of answer the question needs.

Comment: @Marlonchosky - if at least one validation fails , i can stop there and want to get the error message at Main()..I have 5 or 6 more validation to do and and few more inputs

Comment: Thanks for the help..I was able to solve the issue..Sorry I couldn't give more details about the actual application and actual validations I am doing in real code..The code given in my question is a pseudo-code that somewhat reproduce the issue I was facing...anyway, it is working now..Learning a new language in this lock-down phase of my life!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `StringBuilder()`:

```
class Validator
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }

        public string Msg { get {return sb.ToString();} set; }
        private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


        public bool IsAgeValid()
        {
            if (Age < 18)
            {
                sb.Append("Not old enough");
                return false;
            }
            else if (Age > 25)
            {
                sb.Append("you are very old");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public bool IsLocationValid()
        {
            if (Location == "EARTH")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append("sorry..only for humans");
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool IsValid()
        {
            if (IsAgeValid() && IsLocationValid())
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public string getErrorMessage()
        {

            return Msg;
        }

    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Validator myValidator = new Validator();
        myValidator.Age = 34;
        myValidator.Location = "EARTH";

        if(myValidator.IsValid())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("good");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bad because " + myValidator.getErrorMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the world of OOP and C#.
After reading your question and your comment, I think your problem is related to how you should design the validations for your application in your particular case.
As you said, you have a series of validations (at least 5 validations) to perform on an object of a class, but you want that the first validation that is not fulfilled, to no longer continue with the other validations and indicate which was the validation that was not passed and its message.

First, you should keep in mind that in OOP, everything is class-oriented (unlike other paradigms like procedural or functional programming). So, you must model this concept that you want to validate in a C# class. As I see in the code you write, it is a concept that has age and location, and also based on the validations, I can assume that it is a concept similar to an Individual (an individual has an age, and also has a Location of birth? (earth, mars, etc.)). So, let's define this class in C# like:

```
public class Individual {
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you want to have a validator for this entity with some conditions that must be met. These conditions are also called validation rules or business rules (terminology used in programming). Business rules can be general or for a particular process of your application (for example, a validation of individuals for a process of buying travel tickets to another planet, buying tickets to a cinema, etc.). In this case, I will assume that this is a general validation, so we will model this "validator concept" into a class, something like this:

```
public class GeneralIndividualValidator { }
```

Now, in OOP there are many principles, a known principle is the [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), that is, each class that is created must be responsible for some tasks, and must not extend to give other responsibilities different from those that were designed in its creation. With this in mind, the general Validator class should only be responsible for performing general validations for the individual and reporting the validation errors. So, a validate method is defined, which will perform the task of validating an individual, something like this:

```
public class GeneralIndividualValidator {
    public void Validate(Individual individualToValidate) { }
}
```

As you see, the validate method receives an individual object, representing the individual to be validated.
Now, let's define these series of general validations, considering:

- As you mentioned, if one validation is not fulfilled, you should no longer continue with the other validations.
- You only want to get the error message; you don't want to get anything else.

Due to these considerations, the validate method would no longer return void, but it could return a string, containing the reason for the validation that was not fulfilled. Thus, we could redefine this method as follows:

```
public class GeneralIndividualValidator {
    public string Validate(Individual individualToValidate) {
        // Validating the age.
        if (individualToValidate.Age < 18) {
            return "Not old enough";
        }

        if (individualToValidate.Age > 25) {
            return "you are very old";
        }

        // Validating the location.
        if (individualToValidate.Location != "EARTH") {
            return "sorry..only for humans";
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, in an example console application, we will test how this validator would be used:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var individual = new Individual { Age = 12, Location = "EARTH"};
        var validator = new GeneralIndividualValidator();
        var result = validator.Validate(individual);

        if (result != null) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Validation error: {result}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I hope this has given you a guide on how to design your application considering the needs of your business or problem.

Other points I should consider:

- In this code, the validate method returns only one string indicating the reason. However, in future updates of your application, you may require other information in addition to the message, such as a code of the validation that was not fulfilled, so that you can act with this information in a different way.
- In this code, there is an approach of "if one validation is not fulfilled, do not continue with the other validations". However, this is just one approach, another approach might be to want to know all (or partially all) of the non-compliant validations for a given object. If this were the need, the validator code could be rewritten, or a new validator class could be written with this new approach.
- There are tools on the internet that help (and a lot) with validations. One tool is the [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) library. Once you improve your knowledge with the principles of OOP and features of the C# language, you should check that library.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the second if statement is getting in the way, which is redundant if IsValid returns a bool. Give the below code a try and see if it works as you expect:

```
if(myValidator.IsValid())
{
    Console.WriteLine("good");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("bad because " + myValidator.getErrorMessage());
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. I edited my question to show where I have problem

Comment: Is your main method in the Validator class or inside the program class?

Answer (score 0):

Create only single validate method and put all your validation logic in single method. Put an list of string which contains all the error messages and return that list check count of errors in main if it is zero that is valid no error if it is greater then zero show the list of errors that way you can show multiple errors to user. OR you can return boolean and use list of string as ref/out parameter and fill it with errors.

See the example below

```
        class Validator
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }


        public bool IsValid(ref System.Collections.Generic.List<string> errors)
        {
            bool isValid = true;

            try
            {
                if (Age < 18)
                {
                    errors.Add("Not old enough");
                }
                else if (Age > 25)
                {
                    errors.Add("you are very old");
                }

                if (Location != "EARTH")
                {
                    errors.Add("sorry..only for humans");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errors.add(ex.Message);
            }

           IsValid = (errors.Count > 0);

           return IsValid;

        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Validator myValidator = new Validator();
        myValidator.Age = 34;
        myValidator.Location = "EARTH";

        System.Collections.Generic.List errors = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();

        if (myValidator.IsValid(ref errors))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("good");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string error in errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("bad because " + error);
            }
        }
    }
```